# How to fix broken woocommerce quantity buttons

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site with a custom theme and Woocommerce installed. The problem I am having is that buttons to increase the quantity (+/-) are not working. When a quantity button is clicked, it doesn't change the quantity value and the button jumps to the left. I assume it must be a problem between the theme and Woocommerce as Woocommerce works flawlessly elsewhere.

Does anybody know how to fix the woocommerce quantity buttons so that they increase/decrease the quantity field.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem but <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"> should be comma seperated.

Comment: "initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" -- As a tablet user, I wish I could get a hold of every punk developer who needlessly added that (or OnSwipe, for that matter) to their site. Part of me would want to smash their fingers with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was interested, it turned out that some styling from the theme was applying the css: `left:1px;` when the quantity buttons has the pseudo-class :active. So when a quantity button was clicked, the button was being moved to the left without the onclick event firing.